# Android + Appium : How to select date/value from datePicker or NumberPicker?

Tags: automated-testing, android, appium, mobile-automation

How to handle NumberPicker or DatePicker using Appium? I am not able to select value. If you use Xpath its also not working :(

How to select date/value from datePicker or NumberPicker?

Comment: Can you execute jQuery? Have you tried to use jQuery methods?

Comment: yes, but failed. Is it workin at your end?

Comment: it it working, but i used only in web browser. can you provide the jQuery  code that you tried?

Comment: oh - but I am targeting android device. Any solution for that?

Comment: what technology is used for that picker? if is jQuery then using jQuery datepicker api sould work, if not check what technology is used an see if you can write some script that works. If you can provide more details or what have you tried it would be great. For jQ should be something like: jQuery('selector for datepicker').datepicker( 'setDate', '-10' );

Comment: I am using Java + Appium and wanted to automate customize numberPicker.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706492/how-to-change-date-in-datepicker-using-appium and this https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/312

Comment: @lauda Thanks for helping me. Unfortunately I have tried yday all solutions given in SO question. Those are not working for me. Open + Known issue sucks realy

Comment: Try asking a dev for help if possible. hope you find a good solution.